# NiFi: Is there any form to merge all flowfiles in one based in one key?

Tags: json, merge, apache-nifi

I'm working with NiFi and JSONs, trying to enrich the data before doing some transformations.

I've divided the JSON into a lot of little jsons with SplitJson. Now, I need to merge it depending in one key.

Actually, I'm able to merge it all in one, with MergeContent, and Defragment as Merge Strategy. but I can not use Correlation Attribute Name. If I use it, it will fail because less fragments are provided (than the number of fragments present in the original JSON).

e.g.

I have this jsons

```
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime1" }
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime1" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime1" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime1" }
------------------
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime2" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime2" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime2" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime2" }
------------------
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
{ "id":"aaa", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
{ "id":"bbb", "value":1, "datetime":"datetime3" }
```

My goal is:

```
{ "id":"aaa", "datetime":"datetime1", "value":2 }
{ "id":"bbb", "datetime":"datetime1", "value":2 }
{ "id":"aaa", "datetime":"datetime2", "value":1 }
{ "id":"bbb", "datetime":"datetime2", "value":3 }
{ "id":"aaa", "datetime":"datetime3", "value":4 }
{ "id":"bbb", "datetime":"datetime3", "value":2 }
```

I want to merge it based on a key: id and datetime, concatenated. I have hundreds of different flowfiles for each pair id-datetime, and hundred of thousands of different flowfiles.

If I use Bin-Packing algorithm, it doesn't work properly.

I can use Jolt transformations to sum it, but I think it will be so inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried convertRecord processors?

1- ConvertRecord

2- UpdateRecord to have a field id+datetime
3- SplitRecord according to field defined in 2-
4- Merge Back with MergeRecord with Correlation Attribute name on field generated in 3-